# Is there a way to take the best records using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a database with million of records, would it be a possible way to take the best records (ie. rows with the most populated columns)

```
SEQ_ID | PERSON_ID | GENDER | DOB        | COUNTRY
1      |  A000001  |  Male  | 01-01-1970 | 
2      |  A000001  |        |            | Indonesia
```

Would it be possible to take the 2 Records to combine it into 1? E.g

```
SEQ_ID | PERSON_ID | GENDER | DOB        | COUNTRY
1      |  A000001  |  Male  | 01-01-1970 | Indonesia
```

Comment: we are not clear with your problem definition. kindly suggest us what exactly you want to achieve and what you have tried?

Comment: Your first question is not clear enough to me. The second one is yes. Simplest one you can try is to left join the table with itself.

Comment: SELECT T1.ID, T1.PERSON_ID, NVL(T1.GENDER , T2.GENDER) AS GENDER, NVL(T1.DOB , T2.DOB) AS DOB, NVL(T1.COUNTRY , T2.COUNTRY) AS COUNTRY
FROM TABLE_NAME T1
 LEFT JOIN TABLE_NAME T2 ON T1.PERSON_ID = T2.PERSON_ID AND T1.SEQ_ID <> T2.SEQ_ID

Answer (score 0):

With your example, you can use aggregation:

```
select MIN(SEQ_ID), PERSON_ID, MAX(GENDER), MAX(DOB), MAX(COUNTRY)
from t
group by PERSON_ID;
```

It is not clear if this will work generally on your data, but this does answer the question that you asked.  If this doesn't work, you should ask a *new* question, with more appropriate data and explanation of the logic you want to use.